# Radius of convergence of a power series convergent for $s \in [0,1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Suppose a power series converges to a holomorphic function $F(s)$ for $s \in [0,1)$.

I think that in that case, the power series converges to $F(s)$ for $s$ (complex) such that $|s|<1$, but i don't how to prove it...

Is enough to use rotations? I can't see how to prove it...

Thanks, and if you found it in any book, tell me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a power series centered at $0$ converegs at some $z\in\mathbb C$, then it converges absolutely at every $w\in\mathbb C$ such that $|w|<|z|$.

Since your series converges for every $s\in[0,1)$, it follows from the previous paragraph that it converges absolutely for each $z\in\mathbb C$ such that $|z|<1$. Therefore, the radius of convergence is at least $1$.

Comment: why is your first paragraph true? I can't see it...

Comment: Because if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ converges and $|w|<|z|$, then$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty|a_nw^n|=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left|\frac wz\right|^n|a_nz^n|$$and this series converges, by the comparaison test and because the sequence $\bigl(|a_nz^n|\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded.

Comment: Is $|a_n z^n|$ is bounded because the series is Cauchy?

Comment: @GuillermoMosse It is bounded because $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_nz^n=0$. And this is true because the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ converges.